# SQLite: mass updating a field without cursor

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Records (
RecordIndex INTEGER NOT NULL,
...
Some other fields
...
Status1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
Status2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
UpdateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Records PRIMARY KEY (RecordIndex ASC))
```

And an Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Records_Status ON ClientRecords
  (Status1 ASC, Status2 ASC, RecordIndex ASC)
```

I need to fetch the records of a certain status one by one, so i used this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM RECORDS
WHERE RecordIndex > @PreviousIndex
AND Status1 = @Status1
AND Status2 = @Status2
LIMIT 1
```

But now I need to fetch the records sorted by another field, but this field is not unique for each record, so I can not use it in the same way. So I decided to add a new SortIndex field to my table.

As there are no cursors in SQLite, I am doing the following to initialize the values for SortIndex.
First I create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Sort (
SortIdx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
RecordIdx INTEGER )
```

Then I fill this table in the correct sort order:

```
INSERT INTO Sort
  SELECT NULL, RecordIndex
  FROM Records
  ORDER BY SomeField ASC, RecordIndex ASC
```

Then I create an index on the temporary table:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Sort_RecordIdx ON Sort (RecordIdx ASC)
```

Then I update the SortIndex field in my Records table:

```
UPDATE Records
SET SortIndex =
  (SELECT SortIdx
   FROM Sort
   WHERE RecordIdx = RecordIndex)
```

Then I drop the temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE Sort
```

And finaly I create a new index on my Records table

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Records_Sort ON Records
  (Status1 ASC, Status2 ASC, SortIndex ASC)
```

This allows me to do the following select

```
SELECT *
FROM Records
WHERE SortIndex > @PreviousSortIndex
AND Status1 = @Status1
AND Status2 = @Status2
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is, as the table contains around 500K records the whole thing takes around 2 minutes. It would probably have been a lot faster to initialize SortIndex with a cursor, but SQLite lacks this feature :(

Is there a faster way to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an `UPDATE` with a correlated subquery, you should consider the [`INSERT OR REPLACE`](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) feature of SQLite, which will perform an `UPDATE` of a whole row when the primary key is a duplicate:

```
UPDATE Records
   SET SortIndex =
       (SELECT SortIdx
          FROM Sort
         WHERE RecordIdx = RecordIndex)
```

becomes

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Records (RecordIndex, SortIndex, ...)
SELECT RecordIndex, SortIdx, ... FROM another_temporary_table_containing_all_columns.
```

Instead of using a temporary table containing all columns you can of course use a SELECT which joins the old table and the new one: try this inside the SQLite shell

```
CREATE TABLE original (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(2, 'bar');
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(3, 'baz');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE id_remap(old_id INTEGER, new_id INTEGER);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO id_remap(old_id, new_id) VALUES(2,3);
INSERT INTO id_remap(old_id, new_id) VALUES(3,2);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO original (id, content)
SELECT b.new_id, a.content
  FROM original a
 INNER JOIN id_remap b
    ON b.old_id = a.id;

SELECT * FROM original;
```

Result:

```
1|foo
2|baz
3|bar
```

Another option if you need to do mass updates but do not want a correlated subquery is to perform the join in a view, and to create a trigger `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` on that view. A problem is that you cannot have constraints that fail during the process. I suppose that the constraints are checked for each row so that might be very slow.

In the SQLite shell:

```
CREATE TABLE original (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(2, 'bar');
INSERT INTO original(id, content) VALUES(3, 'baz');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE id_remap(old_id INTEGER, new_id INTEGER);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO id_remap(old_id, new_id) VALUES(3,6);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW tmp_id_mapping
    AS
SELECT a.content, b.old_id, b.new_id
  FROM original a
 INNER JOIN id_remap b
    ON b.old_id = a.id;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tmp_trig_id_remap
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF content ON tmp_id_mapping
    FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE original
       SET id = new.new_id
     WHERE id = new.old_id;
   END;

UPDATE tmp_id_mapping
   SET content = 'hello';

SELECT * FROM original;
```

Result:

```
1|foo
2|bar
6|baz
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. But this isn't realy workable as the table is very large, it contains 500k+ records and a lot of columns, so creating a temporary table with all columns would require a lot of memory. But I'll try it anyway to see if it's realy that much faster. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for added more ideas and examples. I tried your first idea, but SQLiteSpy seems to hang when I tried to copy the whole table into the temporary table (what's your favorite SQLite query tool ?). I then tried you idea with the join. As I don't want to change my primary key but just add a new SortIndex field, I kept my Sort temporary table and filled it the same way as before. I then launched the update `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Records(RecordIndex, ..., UpdateDate, SortIndex) SELECT RecordIndex, ..., UpdateDate, SortIdx) FROM Records INNER JOIN Sort ON RecordIdx = RecordIndex` ...

Comment: ... and it took twice a long as my initial update of only the SortIndex field (see initial question). Unless I'm doing something wrong, it seems this isn't a solution either. But thanks for the ideas !

Answer (score 0):

**Main answer**

I think, that this impossible to have quick insert in SQLlite ~500k records with indexes (and many indexes in future).

I hope someone will invent new wheel here.

---

Mark, I think you should avoid this type of dynamically added indexes and just add other classic indexes, no matter how much do you need them.

Also cursors not always good idea in any DMBS -- only if we need complex logic, but here in simple order by, I think it`s over-ing.

Just add classic indexes -- even if they non unique.

Or post here more details about why exactly you fill, that you should choose some dynamic way.

Also sqlite, as I [see](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), supports offset.

---

**SQL for tests**

```
-- init
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `records` (
  `RecordID` int(10) default NULL,
  `Status` int(10) default NULL,
  `SomeField` char(50) default NULL,
  `RecordIndex` int(11) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

truncate `records`;
INSERT INTO `records` (`RecordID`, `Status`, `SomeField`, `RecordIndex`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a', 35),
    (2, 1, 'b', 20),
    (3, 1, 'c', 42);

-- 1st select
SELECT * FROM records WHERE Status = 1 ORDER BY SomeField ASC, RecordIndex ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;

-- update
update records set `Status` = 2 where RecordID = 1;

-- select next
SELECT * FROM records WHERE Status = 1 ORDER BY SomeField ASC, RecordIndex ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: First of all, the index IDX_Records_Sort is not dynamic. The table is filled once, no records are added later, so the SortIndex field only needs to be "calculated" once, and the index is created right after the table is filled. Second, the select "SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Status1 = @Status1 AND Status2 = @Status2 ORDER BY SomeField ASC , ClientIndex ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET @PreviousIndex" will not work as both statuses can be changed, in which case the offset won't be correct anymore.

Comment: @Marc, how often this inicialization happens? What does mean "once"?

Also could you describe your strange logic: why does something could change during read?

Comment: @Alexander, the table is filled once, with bulk inserts, most of the fields will never change (including the field which is used for the sort), except for the 2 status fields. The user wants to view the records with a certain status on screen in order of the sortfield. He will review each record in turn and eventually update the statusses. Then he will display the "next" record. So, although he selected a record by the 2 status values, he can update the status values before selecting the next record. This is why the offset method won't work. Thanks.

Comment: @Marc, I still think, that something over-g here. Even if user changes something, then index become non-usable, right?

Could you provide more details on your default workflow -- and which queries do you use on each action of user?

Comment: Also I don`t think, that `SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Status1 = @Status1 AND Status2 = @Status2 ORDER BY SomeField ASC , ClientIndex ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET @PreviousIndex` will not work -- as it straight as a line. Then you hiding something another important from us? :)

Comment: @Alexander, a little example. To keep it simple, let's use only 1 status, and the user want to review records with status = 1. Let's say there 3 records what that status, in the correct order (SomeField ASC, RecordIndex ASC), with RecordIndex = 35, 20 and 42. If I select the first with `SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Status = 1 ORDER BY SomeField ASC, RecordIndex ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` I would get record 35. Now the user changes the status of that record to 2. If I now would select the 2nd record by using OFFSET 1 I would get record 42 and not record 20. To be continued...

Comment: ... And I can not manually decrement the offset, as other concurent users could have changed the status of records too. In my method I will always find the next record with the correct status as I use the previous SortIndex to find the next one. (btw, it seems I seems I accidently used ClientIndex instead of RecordIndex in my previous example, which is the name of the column in the "real" problem :)

Comment: @Mark, yes, you are right. But I think it should be ruled by some app logic. Like when we change status -- then not increment offset.

Comment: But what I dislike more -- is that in this way we will need many more additional indexes everytime, customer requests some new "order by"s.

As an another way I offer you to select all record ids, with which user currently working in app or in DB, like some table: session_record (session_id, record_id). Where session is some table like (session_id, user_id). Then you will also have history in your app :)

Comment: Just note, that inserting in any DBMS in table with indexes will be always slow -- I know it from MSSQL and from MySQL.

Comment: @Alexander, I see you added an example to your answer. The primary key of my table is RecordIndex, not RecordID, and of course there are a lot more records in the table, but for the example those 3 had status = 1. And as I said, your example of 'select next' won't work as you will skip a record. But thanks anyway.